# Files saved from Chrome trigger 403 when used in web projects

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Whenever I open an image or text file in Chrome and hit save, then try to load it into a web project, I receive 403 errors. The only way I've found to reset the permissions on these files is to upload the file to an FTP server then download it all over again.

I've had this happen on multiple machines now, so I figure it's more widespread than just one install. Do you know any way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you load it into a web project?

Comment: For example, if I am loading in a Javascript file from a <script> tag I will get a 403.

Comment: What server? Any logs? File type, user permissions?